# How can get a normal array without quote after being placed in html dataset

Tags: node.js, arrays, dataset

I am using express js on my server and ejs as a template engine.

After getting array from my database, I send it to ejs, I then store the data in a dataset in the ejs, while trying to get the dataset using vanilla javascript, I realized that the dataset has stringify my array... How can I get it back as an array?

**//ejs**

```
<div class="news_grid" data-kkk="<%=newsData%>">

let a = document.querySelector(".news_grid").dataset.kkk
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the template variable is a properly formatted JSON string, eg, when rendering:

```
newsData: JSON.stringify(newsData)
```

Then, in your frontend JS, parse the dataset into an object first:

```
const newsData = JSON.parse(document.querySelector(".news_grid").dataset.kkk);
// do stuff with newsData.a
```